# Scroll when using iphone with overflow-y: auto in react hidde components of the table

Tags: ios, reactjs, scroll

I'm working in a web page in react and it seeems like the scroll in "y" is causing that the header of my table dissapears, I'm testing on iphone 6 and this is the part of the code where I'm using the scroll, inside a table. When I scroll the header is hidden, someone knows how to solve it? In android, Windows 10 and others devices works well.

```
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

When I change to this the header is scrolleable too, but disappears the first element of the table

```
position: relative;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
height: 100%;
```

I attach a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tableexample-g84sn?file=/src/Components/Table/styled/scrollableY.js

Comment: Please add other styles and elements that might be affecting it or create a sandbox or jsfiddle link where it can be reproduced

Comment: Yes I've just added it